# Use an external list to remove data from rows

Tags: r

I have a data frame

```
df <- data.frame(
    A = c(4, 2, 7),
    B = c(3, 3, 5),
    C = c("Expert,Foo", "Bar,Wild", "Zap")
  )
```

and a second one which I would like to use as index to remove rows which contain the specific values

```
mylist <- data.frame(rtext = c("Foo","Bar"))
```

So I tried this:

```
subset(df, C %in% mylist$rtext)
```

How can I remove the specific rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it is a partial match, we can use `grep`.  We `paste` the elements of 'myList' column 'rtext' into a single string with delimiter `|` which implies `OR`, then get a logical index with `grepl` on the 'C' column of 'df', negate (`!`) to change TRUE to FALSE and FALSE to TRUE to `subset` the rows that are not in the 'rtext' of 'mylist'

```
subset(df, !grepl(paste(mylist$rtext, collapse="|"), C))
#   A B   C
#3 7 5 Zap
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `str_detect` from `stringr`

```
df[!stringr::str_detect(df$C,paste(mylist$rtext,collapse = '|')),]
  A B   C
3 7 5 Zap
```

If you need the 100% match , which means `Foooo` will not be removed ,check with `dplyr` and `tidyr` re-format your df 1st , since  `str_detect` and `grepl` are partial match , if you have word like `Expert,Foott` it will still show as match with `Foo`

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df$id=seq.int(nrow(df))
df1=df %>%
        transform(C = strsplit(C, ",")) %>%
        unnest(C)

df[!df$id%in%df1$id[df1$C%in%mylist$rtext],]
```